# Why isn't touchesBegan working properly?

Tags: swift, drag-and-drop, touchesbegan

I have an image that needs to be dragged around on top of another image. When you touch it, touchesBegan only registers if you touch the image at the top of the image or directly above it. Touching the center of the image, or any other part than the top simply does nothing. Have I set this up properly?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    imageView.image = selectedPhoto
    watermarkImageView.image = selectedWatermark
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInView(self.view)
        if watermarkImageView.frame.contains(location) {
            watermarkImageView.center = location
        } 
    } 
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInView(self.view)
        if watermarkImageView.frame.contains(location) {
            watermarkImageView.center = location
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both image views were nested inside another view. I had to change the `location` to reflect that.

```
let location = touch.locationInView(imageContainerView)
```

Comment: Just a note, if your not overriding all 3 touch functions you need to call super at the top of the overriden functions.